# Javascript/jquery visual plugin to filter  list of items

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, filtering

I have an application which shows a list of items.
http://epos-couch.cloudant.com/epos-couch/_design/epos-couch/index.html

The application is based on [backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/)

At the moment the filtering of list items is done using [visualsearch.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/visualsearch/), a wonderful plugin which unfortunately is not so intuitive for non advanced users.

So I should now implement a different way to filter items.

Each item has a number of keys, and I want to use some of them to filter the list.

Before reinventing the wheel I searched around for some plugin, maybe already integrated with backbone, and all I could find was this one http://addyosmani.github.com/backbone.paginator/examples/netflix-client-paging/index.html which paginates results and also allow for filtering. It miss a couple of features (i.e. pre-defined values for filters), but it's nice.

*Before I go on with this plugin, I want to ask if anybody knows about some good plugin (also only jquery, not necessarily integrted with backbone.js) which can do the filtering job I'm looking for.*

many thanks.

**---UPDATE ---**

I'm not searching for a plugin which implements functions, or logic. I'm searching for a VISUAL plugin, something already existing and very smart.

Visualsearch was one, but my users aren't smart enough to use that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm just researching this myself (so I'm not familiar enough with all the features to know if it's exactly what you're looking for), but [Filtrify](http://luis-almeida.github.com/filtrify/) seems to be one of the most robust and easy to use plugins available.

Comment: Hey it seems great.
When back to work I'll check it with more attention and let you know.
as for now.. thanks (and merry Xmas).

Comment: It's definitely a lot more intuitive than the one you were using (which I honestly found a bit difficult to use). I have a feeling that it's exactly what you're looking for, but I'm curious to hear your thoughts because I'm in the midst of figuring this out myself :-) My challenge with it is that it's configured for hardcoding items in a document (which you tag with data attributes) and I haven't figured out yet how to use it with products in a database (or if you even can).

Comment: Just a heads up - You need to update the link to jquery for the demo to work properly (otherwise the filtering panel isn't displayed). Just link to either your own jquery file or the latest version online, or change the path to jquery-1.7.1.min.js in the js folder of filterify-master.

Comment: Hi Chaya... thanks for you comments... would you have the patience of waiting until 7th when I'll be back to work? The plugin seems really cool. See ya

Comment: Absolutely :-) It's on my to-do list for later that week ;-) Enjoy the rest of your vacation :-D

Comment: that's GREAT! To be honest, I'll have to do some work to make it fit to my code... but it's definitely worth of!
thanks.
Bye the way: which is your site?

Comment: So glad to be able to share the wealth :-D My site is click2fit.com (but it's still in development so most of it requires logging in). I'd love to know a bit more about your project because I have a feeling that you and I are probably going to be dealing with some similar issues in the next few weeks and might be able to help each other out more ;-) Would you like to connect in a chat/email and share a bit about our projects?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just implement a search/filter method in the model?  A plugin for this seems like overkill to me...

Comment: ...See comment to @Matt's answer

Answer (score 0):

Backbone's Underscore.js is a library of methods for Backbone Collections.  Assuming your app has all of its Models in a Collection, you can filter it using Underscore's Filter method:

http://underscorejs.org/#filter

Comment: I'm already using the filter method in my webapp! I was searching for a smart visual interface to it. I'll update the question, maybe it's not clear.